# Discord JS - DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I get an error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Programming\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)        
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\Programming\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)      
    at async MessageManager.delete (D:\Programming\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:205:5)
    at async Message.delete (D:\Programming\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:741:5)
    at async AudioPlayer.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\Discord Bot\src\commands\next.js:44:21) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/channels/888095042437259287/messages/909879363472855080',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

when trying to delete prev. message like this:

```
await client.message.channel.send({
            content: `Song "${client.currentSong}" is playing`,
            components: [row],
        })
            .then(message => {
                client.player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, async () => {
                    await message.delete();
                });
            });
```

This code is executing via one more event code:

```
client.player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
    if (!client.loop) client.playlist.shift();
    if (client.playlist.length === 0) return;
    next.run(client.message, client.args, client);
});
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: Why is it `client.message.channel.send`?

Comment: Because when I use loop function, songs are playing without me typing in message, so I created global variable client.message, which remembers the last chat, where I sent message.

Comment: Does the message get deleted already?

Comment: Yes, the message gets deleted, then I get a message `Song "${client.currentSong}" is playing` and then error.

Comment: Also, the first time I execute this thing, it works, and the next song plays, but the second time is where I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an infinite event listener, meaning whenever the audio player goes idle, it will try to delete the message (even if it already got deleted). Change it `client.player.once` so the listener gets deleted on the first time.

```js
.then(message => {
    client.player.once(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, async () => {
        await message.delete();
    });
})
```